# What permissions are needed for Github Actions to create a tag and release for a Protected Tag?

Tags: github, github-actions

I was reading about **protected tags** and [how they can be created](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/configuring-tag-protection-rules)
 on Github through the `Settings` tab of a particular repository.

I have a `github actions` `workflow` which:

1. Creates a new release
2. Since it creates a new release, it also creates a new tag
3. Uploads files and data to the release

Here is an example of my workflow, which has only some of the key parts.

```
name: myExample

on: 
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python 3.8.3
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.8.3"

     ... Some Steps ...

    - name: Create Release
      id: create_release
      uses: actions/create-release@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        tag_name: ${{env.VERSION}}
        release_name: ${{env.RELEASE_STRING}}
        draft: false
        prerelease: false

    - name: Upload Release Asset 1
      id: upload-release-asset-1
      uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
        asset_path: ./test.zip
        asset_name: test.zip
        asset_content_type: application/zip

        ... Some Steps ...
```

I imagine I need to primarily focus on the section:

```
permissions:
  contents: write
```

What do I need to change so that this workflow can write protected tags and generally can work with protected tags?

Currently, my rule for **protected tags** is:

```
*
```

According to [this](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/configuring-tag-protection-rules) article, it says **"GitHub Apps require the `Repository administration: write` permission to modify a protected tag."**

I looked at Github Actions permissions in [this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs) article, but I don't see those permissions.

I now thought I need to create a **Personal Access Token** and use it according to [this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication) article and [this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) article. When creating a **PAT**, I didn't immediately see exactly what was described above with `Repository administration: write`. Perhaps if I'm an `admin` or `maintainer` of the repo, then if I create a **PAT** with full `repo` permissions then that would do it, since the token is associated with me who is `admin` and therefore, I can create a release on the protected branch as an `admin`. I haven't tested this yet, it is just a theory after searching around.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the permissions at a job level so rather than grant the whole action, you set write and can limit to the job:

```
  version:
    permissions: write-all
    name: versioning
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3.3.0
        with:
          fetch-depth: '0'
      - name: Bump version and push tag
        uses: anothrNick/github-tag-action@1.61.0
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          DEFAULT_BUMP: patch
          WITH_V: "true"
    needs: [terraform, security]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Personal Access Token of your account or one of a technical user and use this token while checking out the repo:

```
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
```

The used account need to admin of the repo, then you will be able to update the protected tag whithin github action

Comment: To hopefully provide some context the down-voter did not....

Best not to use a PAT as that creates a dependency on that user, which will cause problems in the future (after all, it's not that user performing the action, it's the CI pipeline, and therefore audit logs should reflect that).

It's far better to use the built in [`secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication)